# How to style text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how to style text in a tkinter widget. For example, a `label` widget with the text: `Hello world!` and style it with a different font, make it bold, or enlarge the text (if you need any info about my OS, or python/tkinter version, just ask me). I have tried typing the font name after the text, but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Here is an informative site on styling text (actually label widgets, but the methods work for almost all widgets with text in them): https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using: `Label(root, text='Hi', font='Ariel 25 bold').pack()`. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks! gladly appreciated